# Flutter web lagging on mobile when i scroll

Tags: flutter

I am making my first website on flutter. I used `Listview.builder` on all pages. On pc it is working perfectly.But in mobile it is unusably lagging and stuttering when i scroll.

I tried primary : false but it is not working. I need help.

Here is my homepage for example (it is lagging for all screens) ;

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    bool isDeviceDesktop = (size.width > 1000);

    List<Widget> items = [
                  const MyCarouselSlider(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50,),
                  AnimatedTextKit(
                    animatedTexts: [
                      TypewriterAnimatedText(
                        'Nayıs Perde , Evinize Şıklık Katar...',
                        textStyle: GoogleFonts.dancingScript(fontSize: 35, color: Colors.white),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        speed: const Duration(milliseconds: 60),
                      )
                    ],
                    totalRepeatCount: 1,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 70,),
                  isDeviceDesktop?const BuildWhysColumnForDesktop():const BuildWhysColumnForMobile(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 70,),
                  isDeviceDesktop?const BuildFeaturingProductsColumnForDesktop():const BuildFeaturingProductsColumnForMobile(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 70,),
                  UnconstrainedBox(child: Dividers.simpleDivider(mediaSize: size)),
                  isDeviceDesktop?EndingContainerForDesktop(size: size):EndingContainerForMobile(size: size),
                  

                ];
    
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: isDeviceDesktop?null:const DoubleFabRow(),
      drawer: const NavDrawer(),
      body: CustomPerformanceOverlay(
        child: Container(
          height: size.height,
          width: size.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/model/background.jpg',),fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const CustomAppBar(),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  primary: false,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return items[index];
                  },
                ),
              )
      
      
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Building with canvaskit fixed the issue. If you have the same issue, in terminal you need to type `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit` when building the web folder.

Comment: I tried your solution but not working on mobile.

Comment: If you implemented my solution and still there is stuttering, then probably your website stutters while downloading images etc. Make sure using listview.builder, and try not to use big sized images, files. And keep rendering with canvaskit.

Comment: I am implementing a mobile app, not a web one. Sorry

Comment: if you are using shrinkWrap : true in your listview.builder , it may also effect performance(try using sliver lists). Other than that , i am out of solutions. I hope you will fix your problem.

Comment: Works for me better than previous